# How to make a physically accurate airplane takeoff

Tags: animation

I have a model of a plane, and a runway, I want to make the plane realistically take off, even after many trys, it looks nothing like a real takeoff, I have tried to make realistic acceleration but the part where the plane rotates to lift of the ground it looks unrealistic? How could I make a plane realistically do its?
[image: What I have so far after many attempts, the acceleration is green and the lift off is blue]

What I have so far after many attempts, the acceleration is green and the lift off is blue

Comment: I noticed the lift off rotation has a key frame right next to the start that would make it turn up rather quickly, then suddenly start moving slowly again. Is it intentional?

Comment: I also would of course recommend looking at videos of actual airplane takeoff for a reference. I’m not sure they actually rotate much until they’re well off the ground, but I’m not sure. Check YouTube for reference videos. A reference is not the artist’s diaper, it’s a tool in your toolbox. :-)